# php shell_exec executing java program

Tags: java, php, shell-exec

In PHP code I try to execute Java program using shell_exec but I get empty line.

When I tried to execute program in bash:

```
#bin/bash

echo "aaa"
```

I get "aaa" but when i tried to execute the same file with

```
#bin/bash

java MainApp
```

I got empty line

This is the java code

```
public class MainApp{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                System.out.print(":]");
        }
}
```

When i do:

```
#bin/bash

echo "aaa"
java MainApp
echo "bbb"
```

I get "aaa bbb"

I wont to get ":]" string
How to make it work?

Maybe printing line with System.out.println(String ) is not the same as echo and printing line is not the same as returning value

Comment: What happens when you execute "java MainApp" from the command line?  Does that produce the results you expect?

Comment: yes Ii get ":]"
Is that safe mode problem?

Comment: Other then your messed up shebang (it should be `#!/bin/bash`), this looks fine. Is your working directory when you run the script the same one the Java app is in?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution?